# EF Code Generation from EDMX. Updating DB model when DB data changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I created an Entity Model and then used code generation to create DBContext classes. When I perform and TSQL update statement in SQL Server on one of my tables, do I have to update my model every time I perform an update when debugging? When I deploy my MVC app, will the model automatically update? Right now I am clicking Run Custom Tool on my Context.tt file. Also, do I get rid of the custom tool property on my former edmx file? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity framework model will **not** update automatically.  If you make changes to columns or tables in the database, you'll need to refresh your model.

If you open the `.edmx` file and right-click in an empty space, there's an option to `Update Model from Database` which will find tables and columns that have changed.  I think you'll have to run your T4 code generation again after updating the model (haven't used T4 myself, so I'm not sure).

Comment: that is what I suspected. Thank you!